# Avoiding Duplicates when appending records in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

I am aware this has been asked multiple times, but for one reason or another the solutions are not working for me.

**Database Layout:**

I have Table1 (Scanner_Location) Who is getting data pulled from another table/ subform on a form (Scanner IBOB) * Holds Columns: FP#, Count, Location, Model_ID, PK-SL_ID

Table2 (Scanner Detail) Holds Two of the three data columns: (FP#, Location PK-SN)
Table3 (Scanner_Model) Holds the last data column, displayed in a subform. (PK-Model_ID)

The user will input FP#, and location in one section of the form, then navigate to the subform, and select multiple Models, and enter the count (Textbox). Once Selected, they click an 'update' button that executes my queries. (Of which I have an update, AND an Append Query)

The problem is, just using an update query doesn't add the records. And using an Append query creates duplicates of the existing data.

**Here's how the flow carries out:**

User selects Model 1 and Model 2 with a count of 4 and an FP# of 100. Clicks update. 
The queries update, and the information enters correctly.

User Selects the same models again (Model_Select), with the same FP# and count, the Table1 has the same information entered again, with a different primary key.

**The goal:**

The append query creates duplicates of existing data. I only want my update and/or append queries to:

Update the existing data - Looking for anything with the same FP#
Add any records that do not exist already (Looking at Model_ID and FP#)

```
INSERT INTO Scanner_Location ( Model_ID, FootPrints_Num, Location_ID, Scanner_Loc_Cnt ) 
SELECT Scanner_Model.Model_ID, [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![fpNum_txt] AS [FP#],
    [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![Location_Cbo_main] AS Location, 
    [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![Scanner_Loc_CntTxt] AS [Count] 
    FROM Scanner_Detail 
    RIGHT JOIN Scanner_Model ON Scanner_Detail.Model_ID = Scanner_Model.Model_ID
    WHERE (((Scanner_Model.SM_Acc_Select)=True) 
        AND ((NOT Exists (SELECT * FROM Scanner_location 
    WHERE (((Forms!Scanner_IBOB!fpNum_txt)=Forms!Scanner_IBOB!fpNum_tx‌​t) 
        And ((Scanner_Model.SM_Acc_Select)=True)); ))=False));
```

Comment: The above is my append query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837911/appending-into-another-table-and-avoiding-duplicates 
Gets me close, but the AND NOT EXISTS doesn't seem to work, or I am not understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No query named 'Update_SLoc_Acc53' - there are 'Update_SLoc_Acc3'  and 'Update_SLoc_Acc54'. I modified 'Update_SLoc_Acc54' because it is the one called by the code.

The query was not pulling the Location_ID from the combobox. I found the Bound Column was set to 1 and should be 0 to reference the Location_ID column because column index begins with 0. Can hide this column from user by setting width to 0.

This query seems to work:

```sql
INSERT INTO Scanner_Location ( Model_ID, FootPrints_Num, Location_ID, Scanner_Loc_Cnt )
SELECT Scanner_Model.Model_ID, [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![fpNum_txt] AS FPNum,
      [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![Location_Cbo_main] AS Location, 
      [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![Scanner_Loc_CntTxt] AS CountMod
FROM Scanner_Model
WHERE (((Scanner_Model.SM_Acc_Select)<>False) 
  AND  (([Model_ID] & [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![fpNum_txt] &
         [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![Location_Cbo_main]) 
        NOT IN (SELECT Model_ID & Footprints_Num & Location_ID FROM Scanner_Location)));
```

Note I did not use # in field name. Advise not to use punctuation/special characters in names with only exception of underscore. Also used CountMod instead of Count as field name.

Why the requirement to select two models? What if one is added and the other isn't?

I have concerns about the db structure.

1. Don't think App_Location and App_Detail should both be linking to other tables. Why is Location_ID the primary key in App_Location as well as primary key in Location_Data? This is a 1-to-1 relationship.
2. Is Serial_Number the serial number for scanner? Why is it a primary key in Telnet? This also results in a 1-to-1 relationship in which case might as well combine them.
3. If an app is associated with a scanner and scanner is associated with a location then don't need location associated with app. Same goes for scanner and telnet.
4. Scanner_Location table is not linked to anything. If purpose of this table is to track a count of models/footprints/locations -- as already advised this is usually not a good idea. Ideally, count data should be calculated by aggregate query of raw data records when the information is needed.

Comment: From the top:
Thank you for noticing the query wasn't pulling the location, I'd been testing with location 0 as test data for a while now. And I did not know that about bound columns.

Did I have '#' as a field name somewhere? If so, was it just a label? Or are you referring to something named "Number" as a form object? I need to know so that I may amend this in my copy of the database. I will fix the 'count' reference. Thank you.

Comment: It's fine if one model is selected, and the other is not. One Tab selects Scanners, the other displays the accessories that may be shipped with the base units. (Such as battery packs, or docks)

Why should App Location and App Detail be linking to other tables? I'm keeping track of the applications, where they are used, and what the application is. Location ID Should not be replicated for this information, and thus is the primary key for this table. Application Name is also added as a scanner by scanner basis. (Think of this as the State designation for a contact database)

Comment: Serial_Number is the Serial number for a Scanner. Yes, Why is it the primary key in Telnet? I'm trying to separate out the data for Telnet. I don't want Scanner_Detail to hold EVERYTHING for a scanner. 

(If this is the wrong way to do this, please let me know.) However, Telnet I am still working on - as I'm not entirely sure what exact information will be used for that table. If it's just one number, I would of course put it in Scanner_Detail.

Comment: Scanner_location was disconnected in an attempt to fix a few things, I'd forgotten to re-link it. 

Count data for the 'Scanner_Location' table Is user inputted. There is no way to track the accessory data that scanner_location pulls.  (There is no serial number, or unique ID for these accessories. Otherwise they would be on the Scanner_Detail table and I wouldn't have this mess to begin with.)

This count data is only how many sets of units are sent out. It doesn't have any bearing, save displaying how many units should be returning with the record. 
Hopefully this clears up information.

Comment: You had FP# as alias field name in the query. SerialNumber is primary key in two tables. This is 1-to-1 relationship. Might as well be 1 table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use NOT IN, something like:

[some identifier field] NOT IN (SELECT [some identifier field] FROM

Review [EXISTS vs IN](https://accessexperts.com/blog/2013/10/02/whether-to-exists-or-not-exists-that-is-the-question/)

Comment: After a lot of... trial and error I got the following:

`INSERT INTO Scanner_Location ( Model_ID, FootPrints_Num, Location_ID, Scanner_Loc_Cnt )

SELECT Scanner_Model.Model_ID, [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![fpNum_txt] AS [FP#], [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![Location_Cbo_main] AS Location, [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![Scanner_Loc_CntTxt] AS [Count]

FROM Scanner_Location

WHERE NOT EXISTS ( ([Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![FPNum_txt]) AND (Scanner_Model.SM_Acc_Select=True))

SELECT SM_ACC_SELECT,FPNum_txt
FROM Scanner_Model
WHERE SM_ACC_SELECT  AND FootPrints_Num ([Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![FPNum_txt])
);
`

Comment: There's a Syntax error after the "Where Not Exists"

Comment: This makes no sense: ([Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![FPNum_txt]) AND (Scanner_Model.SM_Acc_Select=True)). Nor does the WHERE clause in the second subquery. If Count field is for storing an aggregate value, this is not a good practice. Aggregate data should be calculated when needed, not stored. Some sample data would be helpful if you want to provide. Count is a reserved word in Access, should avoid reserved words as names for anything.

Comment: I apologize, I am very new to SQL. And even moreso dealing with user input. 

The count field: 'Scanner_Loc_CntTxt' a user input, and is simply reduced to reduced to 'Count' as a column header in a subform. If that's an issue I'll change it to something more specific.

I'll attempt to host the file when I'm not at work.

WHERE clauses:
I'm trying to say: When inputted text in the 'FPNum_txt' input AND the the models in Scanner_Model are selected 

If Any records that match FPNum_Txt, and the Model Number (PK of Scanner_Model) Exist, don't append. If they do not exist already, Do add

Comment: Here's the link for the the database.https://www.dropbox.com/s/phs16l0l9610t14/ASI%20-%20DEV%200307A.accdb?dl=0

I'm editing append Query 'Update_SLoc_Acc53' This runs from the Scanner_IBOB form, Accessory Tab. 

(You have to input a number for the Footprints Ticket number (101, or 102) Any date, and click the accessory tab button.)

Inputting a number in the count, and selecting two models (First and second) and clicking update will run the query. 

The Scanner_Location table is the table I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following adjusted append query that checks existence of matched *Model_ID* and  *FP_Num* in *Scanner_Location*. If matches do not exist, then query imports selected records as they would be new records and not duplicates. Also, table aliases are used for readability and subquery correlation.

```
INSERT INTO Scanner_Location ( Model_ID, FootPrints_Num, Location_ID, Scanner_Loc_Cnt ) 
SELECT m.Model_ID, [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![fpNum_txt] AS [FP#],
       [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![Location_Cbo_main] AS Location, 
       [Forms]![Scanner_IBOB]![Scanner_Loc_CntTxt] AS [Count] 
FROM Scanner_Detail d
RIGHT JOIN Scanner_Model m ON d.Model_ID = m.Model_ID
WHERE ((m.SM_Acc_Select = True) 
  AND  (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Scanner_Location loc
                    WHERE ((loc.FootPrints_Num = Forms!Scanner_IBOB!fpNum_tx‌​t) 
                      AND  (loc.Model_ID = m.Model_ID)) ) ));
```